# How to get frequency count of unique values in a column groupby another colum? (Pandas)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

In this linked screenshot: I have data in this format on the left, and I need to return a frequency count table that looks like the one on the right side. I know I can use groupby ("Time") and I can get the unique values of the "Type" column by using " df["Type].unique(). But I get stuck in the next steps. Any suggestion?
[Screenshot of the data and expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBGw2.png)

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['Time'], df['Type'])`

Comment: Would be ```df.groupby('Time')['Type'].value_counts()``` when using groupby

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['AM', 'PM', 'AM','AM','PM','PM','AM','PM'],
              'Type':['Egg','Milk','Milk', 'Ham', 'Milk','Ham', 'Milk','Egg']})
```

`.Crosstab()` is what you need:

```
pd.crosstab(df['Time'], df['Type'])
```

Or you could also use `.pivot_table()` with `aggfunc='size'`

```
df.pivot_table(index='Time', columns='Type', aggfunc='size')
```

Or groupby + unstack:

```
df.groupby(['Time', 'Type']).size().unstack()
```

Output:

```
Type  Egg  Ham  Milk
Time                
AM      1    1     2
PM      1    1     2
```

Comment: Thank you a lot all! I will try each out. I googled earlier and found one example that suggested using pd.crosstab() - but I was not sure.

Comment: That's great! Keep coding!